# BibTeX reference page appears at start of pdf from IEEE template

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

When using the IEEE template (LaTeX and BibTeX) the references page appears before the title page. Why is this?

The LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
%
% paper title
% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
The abstract goes here. 
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
% no \IEEEPARstart
This demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE conference papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.7 and later. \cite{dp}
% You must have at least 2 lines in the paragraph with the drop letter
% (should never be an issue)
I wish you the best of success.

\hfill mds

\hfill January 11, 2007

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here.

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.

\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.

\section*{Acknowledgment}
The authors would like to thank...

\end{document}
```

the bib file:

```
@Article{ dp,
  title = {Exact and approximate representations for the sum Dirichlet process},
  author = "Ishwaren, H. and Zarepour, M. ",
  journal = "Can J Stat",
  Volume = 30,
  PAGES = {269–283},
  year = 2002,
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and congratulations for the good example. While the `\bibliographystyle` command can go almost anywhere, the `\bibliography` command should go where you want the bibliography to be typeset.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks! You guys are so much more polite than stack overflow.

Comment: We try hard to be friendly, particularly to newbies. Welcome again.

Comment: I removed several line breaks from your example code. Also I removed your thanks: Usually, we don't put this (and greetings as well) in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\bibliography` needs to go where you actually want your bibliography output (at the end?)